# link_to_remote not updating div

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm using link_to_remote to update a div asynchronously, but it does not work. I have to refresh the page in order to see the change.

I use this to generate the links.
http://ruby.pastebin.com/m1d83be81

```
"padding-left:30px", :display => "table-row" ) do %>
 
  { :success => 'entry_' + entry.id.to_s},
           :url =>{ :controller => :entries, :action => :increment ,:id => entry.id},
           :with => "'amount=' +prompt('Amount')")%> 
  { :success => 'entry_' + entry.id.to_s},
           :url =>{ :controller => :entries, :action => :decrement ,:id => entry.id},
           :with => "'amount=' +prompt('Amount')")%> 
 { :success => 'entry_' + entry.id.to_s},
           :url =>{ :controller => :entries, :action => :update ,:id => entry.id},
           :with => "'amount=' +prompt('Amount')")%>
```

The corresponding actions all look like this:

```
  def increment
    @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
    @entry.amount += params[:amount].to_i
    @entry.save!
    render :partial=>"entry", :object=>@entry
  end
```

Comment: What's in the "entry" partial? Any JavaScript errors in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the :success tag in your update clause and test:

```
:update => 'entry_' + entry.id.to_s
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found it helpful to specify the div to be updated in an :update in the controller action.